# Get git tags created over the last year

Tags: git, shell, tags

I want to create a 2022 wrapped for our engineering teams. For that I need the count of releases (=git tags) for every repository from the last year.

However, I couldn't find out how to do this using the command line.

The solution probably would include some variation of

```
git log --since=1.year.ago --oneline
```

---

After walking through @torek's great explanation I ended up with this:

```
git log --since=1.year.ago --tags --no-walk --oneline | wc -l
```

Comment: `git log --tags --since=<...> | wc -l` ?!

Comment: @LazyBadger Why do you post an answer as a comment?

Comment: @LazyBadger's answer unfortunately also doesn't work - it returns a way too high count. That's because `git log --tags` isn't only returning tags, but commits AND attached tags (if any).

Comment: Show sample of output, it can be cleaned, sure. Sidenote: for complex queries and filters I always recommend *at least to think* about Mercurial's power with its real DSL for revsets + hggit. This sweet pair can save a lot of time and eliminate most headache

Comment: @LazyBadger Sample output: https://gist.github.com/ubuntudroid/068fab070a3e436f4cbac7860ad3e980

As you can see there are plain commits with no tags in there.

Comment: @SebDieBln - as you can see from discussion (and gist), because it was (expected) dirty idea, not ready-to-use solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two "kinds" of tags in Git:

- *annotated* tags carry extra information, including the date when the tag itself was created;
- *lightweight* tags carry no extra information.

All tags identify some Git object, usually a commit, and each *commit* has *two* date-and-time stamps attached.  Be careful that when using an annotated tag, you consider the *tag's* date, rather than one of the two *commit* dates.  Since lightweight tags have no tagger date, you must choose what to do with them: ignore them entirely, or perhaps pretend that the tagger date is one of the two commit date stamps.

If you have no lightweight tags, this complication goes away.

The `git tag` and `git for-each-ref` commands are the main two commands for inspecting tags directly.  Both will let you sort the tags by whatever sorting key you like; using `--sort=taggerdate` (oldest first) or `--sort=-taggerdate` (newest first) is likely what you want here.

You may, however, not be looking for the tagger date in the first place.  Suppose *commit* `a123456` was created on 29 Dec 2021, and then *tag* `v3.1415` was created on 3 Jan 2022.  Does this count as a release from 2022, or from 2021?  You'll need to decide how to handle the fact that an annotated tag's date is separate from the two dates in the commit it tags (assuming it tags a commit in the first place).

So, your first task is to decide how to handle all these fiddly details.  Then you can pick one of the `--sort` options *or* use a modified version of [Lazy Badger's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828167/get-git-tags-created-over-the-last-year#comment132058838_74828167): add `--no-walk` to the `git log` command and you'll get just the tagged commits, sorted by committer date (by default, though you can sort by author date if you wish).  Note that Git *will not* use the tagger date here.

If you choose to go with `git for-each-ref refs/tags`—which will be the most robust solution once you handle all the fiddly details—you'll probably want to:

- list out the tag names, selected dates, and target object hash IDs;
- check whether the tag itself is annotated, if necessary, and that the target object is a commit;
- if sorting with `-taggerdate` or `-authordate` or `-committerdate` (depending on the decision you made here), discard the remaining tags as soon as you get one that's "too old"

and now you have the list of tags and all auxiliary information needed.  This is just a small matter of script programming, using for-each-ref's formatting directives and some simple shell (sh/bash) script for instance.  It's probably possible to use the fancy `%(if)` directives, but I find that they are very messy to use compared to writing a bit of shell code.

Comment: Nice shot! Can you comment (for everybody, not just me) in your answer, what will be "not so cool" with f.e. **such expanded oneliner** (I can't test due to missing Git) `git log --oneline --decorate --simplify-by-decoration --no-walk --tags` for *only-annotated-tags repo*?

Comment: @LazyBadger `--simplify-by-decoration` just means that commits that get walked *and* have a branch or tag name referring to them get selected for display, so combining it with `--no-walk` is a bit pointless: commits selected on the command line (via `--tags`) will get displayed anyway. It works fine, and if we don't care too much about edge cases like "committed in late Dec, tagged in Jan" you'll get useful output.

Comment: I just can't imagine which "noizy" output got OP, thus try to write (from head) "most bulletproof" solution. BTW, with HG I wrote selector in approx. 5 minutes and most time spent on template, not revset

Comment: @torek awesome explanation! I ended up with really using the combination of @LazyBadger's explanation and `--no-walk` and got exactly what I was looking for: `git log --since=1.year.ago --tags --no-walk --oneline | wc -l`. So thanks to both of you!

Comment: @LazyBadger: yes, hg's actual revset selector language is significantly more powerful than Git's loose and floppy "select some then walk, and then maybe prune some for display purposes" thing. Alas, as often happens, people seem to like the "worse" version more... (See also https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs201/projects/2010-11/WorseIsBetter/index43bb.html?title=Main_Page&oldid=86)